# MVCSiteMapProvider - recently added keywords and now they're populating in the link for the MenuHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using the MVCSiteMapProvider in my MVC3 site and I've recently added meta keywords and description to my nodes in the mvc.sitemap

> < mvcSiteMapNode controller="Home" action="Index" title="Home" description="" keywords="home, home page, welcome" >

... for example.

Then my view populates it like so:

> @{ string title = "";
>         string keywords = "";
>         string description = "";
>
> ```
>   if (SiteMap.CurrentNode != null)
>   {
>       title = SiteMap.CurrentNode["title"];
>       keywords = SiteMap.CurrentNode["keywords"];
>       description = SiteMap.CurrentNode["description"];
>   }
> ```
>
> }
>
> < title>>@title< /title>>
>
> < meta name="keywords" content="@keywords" / >
>
> < meta name="description" content="@description" / >

On all my pages I use:

> @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(0, true, true, 1)

Ever since I started putting content in the keywords section the links in the menu populate like this:

> < a href="/?keywords=home%20%2C%20Home%20Page%2C%20welcome" >Home< /a >

I'm not sure why this showed up and I'd like it not to be there.
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as far as I know an undocumented MvcSiteMapProvider feature. All unknown attributes on a node is inserted as RouteValues default.
To ignore the keywords attribute, edit your sitemap settings in web.config and add "keyword" to the attributesToIgnore.
If you are using the default inserted configuration the MvcSiteMapProvider should already have attributesToIgnore defined.
Below is the default settings with keywords added to attributeToIgnore:

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider"
      type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"
      siteMapFile="~/Mvc.Sitemap"
      securityTrimmingEnabled="true"
      cacheDuration="5"
      enableLocalization="true"
      scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="true"
      excludeAssembliesForScan=""
      includeAssembliesForScan=""
      <!-- Added keywords -->
      attributesToIgnore="bling,visibility,keywords"
      nodeKeyGenerator="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultNodeKeyGenerator, MvcSiteMapProvider"
      controllerTypeResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
      actionMethodParameterResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultActionMethodParameterResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
      aclModule="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule, MvcSiteMapProvider"
      siteMapNodeUrlResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
      siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"
      siteMapProviderEventHandler="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProviderEventHandler, MvcSiteMapProvider"/>
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```